# CrossThreadMessagingException while using backgroundworker windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have a windows form application and have a button which calls a function

I am copying large files from one place to another.

It is taking a long time so I decided to use a progress bar.
I need to invoke the Background process  from the button click

The `copyItems()` function iterates through the list items and copies the items from another place. It in turn calls a  function `CopyListItem` which copies one item.

I set a textbox value in the UI  but it returns an

> **An exception 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.CrossThreadMessagingException' occurred**`

How do I invoke the **copy function in the backgroundworker todo event**
When I call the runworkerasync method in the click event I get an error

```
    private void btnCopyItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

I created a class

```
public partial class WorkerItem
{
    Helper Helper = new Helper();
    Complaints comp = new Complaints();
    public void CopyItem(SPListItem sourceItem, string destinationListName, string destServerURL)
    {
        //Copy sourceItem to destinationList
        try
        {
           // copies file from one location to another
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Helper.LogtoList("Copy List ", string.Format("  {0} Message {1} Source {2} Stack trace {3}", ex.InnerException.ToString(), "Message " + ex.Message + "Source" + ex.Source + "Stack trace" + ex.StackTrace));
        }
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    this.Text=e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        WorkerItem workerItem = (WorkerItem)e.Argument;

        // check if the site valid
        Helper.siteName = txtSite.Text;
        {                          
            progressBar1.Maximum = itemscoll.Count;
            foreach (SPListItem sourceItem in itemscoll)
            {
                date = sourceItem["Date_x0020_Created"].ToString();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
                {                               
                    workerItem.CopyItem(sourceItem, Helper.destinationListName, Helper.destServerURL);
                }
            }
        }

        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Items Copied {0}", Helper.ItemsCopied.ToString()));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Helper.LogtoList("Main Function ", string.Format("{0} Message {1} Source {2} Stack trace {3}", ex.InnerException.ToString(), "Message " + ex.Message + "Source" + ex.Source + "Stack trace" + ex.StackTrace));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting the exception is because you are setting `progressBar1.Maximum = itemscoll.Count;` inside the `DoWork` event of your BackgroundWorker.
**No UI changes** should occur inside your DoWork event, that is what the `ProgressChanged` event is for.

There is also no indication inside your code that you are reporting any progress back to the main thread.

The way you should be handling your example is as follows:

```
private void btnCopyItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Set the progressBar1.Maximum here before we call the background worker
  // This is what caused your exception, since it is an UI element that you are trying to change
  // inside your BackgroundWorker thread
  progressBar1.Maximum = 100;             // % based (Could be set onces and always left at 100)
  progressBar1.Maximum = itemscoll.Count; // x/y based
  // Either we use a percentage based progressbar or an x/y progressbar.
  // !!!! Choose one and use the appropriate values for it !!!!

  backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    WorkerItem workerItem = (WorkerItem)e.Argument;

    Helper.siteName = txtSite.Text;
    {
      // Variable for our progress calculation
      double curProgress; // % based

      // Since we need to report progress, let us use a for-loop instead of a foreach-loop
      for (int i = 0; i < itemscoll.Count-1; i++)
      {
        SPListItem sourceItem = itemscoll[i];
        date = sourceItem["Date_x0020_Created"].ToString();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
        {
          workerItem.CopyItem(sourceItem, Helper.destinationListName, Helper.destServerURL);
        }

        // Calculate the current progress and call the ReportProgress event of our BackgroundWorker
        curProgress = ((double)i / (double)itemscoll.Count) * 100;                // % based
        ((BackgroundWorker)sender).ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32(curProgress));  // % based

        // If we only go x/y progress based, then just send back our current state
        ((BackgroundWorker)sender).ReportProgress(0, i);  // x/y based
      }
    }

    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Items Copied {0}", Helper.ItemsCopied.ToString()));
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Helper.LogtoList("Main Function ", string.Format("{0} Message {1} Source {2} Stack trace {3}", ex.InnerException.ToString(), "Message " + ex.Message + "Source" + ex.Source + "Stack trace" + ex.StackTrace));
  }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  // % based
  progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
  this.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();

  // x/y based
  progressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(e.UserState);
  this.Text = Convert.ToInt32(e.UserState).ToString();
}
```

**Note the two different progress reporting methods!**
One uses the percentage based reporting and the other uses the x/y based reporting.
Which one you want to use is up to you, but you will need to choose one and use that

More reading about the BackgroundWorker can be found at:
[MSDN: BackgroundWorker Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[MSDN: How to: Run an Operation in the Background](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hybbz6ke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

One final note:
You are using `MessageBox.Show` in your BackgroundWorker, this is not advised and you should rather stop your worker thread and return an appropriate error to your main thread to show.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following to avoid this exception.

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
                    //code here you required
});
```

//----------or below code----------

```
this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
                      //code here you required
 });
```